# Non-feature locked emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have just found out that the WP7 emulator is feature locked when I was asked to look into sending emails from my app. I know it is possible to access an unlocked ROM but as this isn't sanctioned it is not something I can do. I also do not have a WP7 phone and cannot get hold of one ye as there isn't the funding as yet to buy one.

So when MS release the full release of the SDK will it remain feature locked or will it act more like a proper phone at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote about "unlocking" the latest emulator image in another Question. You cannot unlock it, but you can access most of the internal features / programs. Take a look at this answer: [Unlock Windows Phone 7 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335667/unlock-windows-phone-7-emulator/7336756#7336756)

Answer (score 0):

Prior to NoDo (and I think perhaps NoDo - don't remember for sure), it was possible, as there was a leaked image.  I never did get it to work properly, though.  But that is irrelevant now, as with the Mango updates (all of the betas and the RC), it no longer works, and there is no unlocked emulator image out there.

Answer (score 0):

There is unlikley to be a "fully featured" emulator released.

You will need to get an actual device for testing so I'd wait on testing this functionality until you have a device. If you know someone who has one you could borrow there's or send them the XAP and ask them to test for you.

Comment: The Android emulator and the Symbian emulators when I worked on those way back seemed to be mostly fully featured so it seems a little odd that WP7 even though the features are available in the emulator they disable them. I guess there is a reason for it and obviously down the line I would need a real phone but until I get one it's something I will have to try to live with.